# What would be the best way to find out changes in the database?

Tags: mysql, reverse-engineering

I am using an application which uses `MySQL` db and recently have got an issue with the application. I just wanted to go back and find out the changes made in DB by app and for this someone suggested me to reverse engineer.

Could any one please suggest me how to start with it (as I am new to reverse engg).

Comment: "Reverse engineering" is nothing that can help here. There are two thing you can take a look at: 1. if you had query logging enabled you obviously can see all modifying queries and 2. compare a current backup snapshot to one of the snapshorts you took before.

Comment: You could insert all existing values in a historic table before comitING the records. then you will have a table will all the previous changes. This will add overhead to the dB so uses it only if needed

Comment: Thanks @arkascha for clearing my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can check **general_logs, binary_logs** of the MySQL database to check all the queries run on the database by app.